# Laravel belongsToMany() date desc

Tags: php, laravel

I use a belongsToMany() in Laravel, but a staff member can have more than one position, I want to bring the staff with the largest date and desc id.

[image: PHP code / MySQL result]

Comment: Few things are wrong here. Why have you named your model in plural? Laravel recommends using singular keywords. Second, why are you using whereRaw and whereHas query in your relation function? The relation function shouldn't have `where` query written along with relations... Lastly, what exactly do you require? How is 10 having the largest date in the first picture? Is that because it has largest of the Ids?

Comment: - I wrote wrong, already Position.php.
- What I want is to find the position the staff is currently working on according to the "action_date" date. So I used interrogation in relation.
- In the first picture, if the dates are the same, use the last added data, ie the largest id.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Person.php**, add a back relation to **Position.php**

```
public function positions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Path\To\Person')->withPivot(['id', 'person_id', 'position_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
}
```

Now you can do something like....

```
$positions = Person::positions()
                   ->wherePivot('action_date', '>=', $date)
                   ->orderBy('person_position.id', 'desc')
                   ->get();

$pivotTable = $positions->map(function($position) {
                return $position->pivot;
              });
```

Let me know if you face any other issue :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This code is for a staff only, I want a code that works with "mysql query". Sample code; "Position::find(1)-persons()->whereBranch(1)->count();" Is there a code that can provide this question?

Comment: @DavutKember In the comment above, **"What I want is to find the position the staff is currently working on..."** How by the above code (that you just commented) are you finding the position? By doing `Position::find(1)`... You already know the position staff is working on. Please be clear.

Comment: I want to find all the staff who work in the position I want.
Please refer to the image database again, the same personnel have three positions. I want the position with the highest date to be valid.
So, according to the last database in the picture, I want "Position::find(2)->persons()->count() query to arrive at 0, and Position::find(9)->persons()->count() query to arrive at 1"

"I apologize for the bad english, I translate it with Google Translate."